# Trying to use getopt with a file that begins with a dash '-' as an argument

Tags: c, unix

I am currently working with the function getopt(). I am implementing a program that is similar to the 'ls' command in Unix.
Everything seems to work correctly, however, if say I have a file named "-xyz",and pass the filename as argument, getopt() doesn't treat it as a file/dir.

For example, if i type: ./myprogram -i Makefile -xyz, I expect the function to treat -xyz as a file/dir but instead it tries to treat it as options.

Here is my code:

```
while((choice = getopt(argc, argv, "ilR")) != -1){  

      switch(choice) {
        
        case 'i':  
            opt->option_i = 1;
            break;
        case 'l':  
            opt->option_l = 1;
            break;
        case 'R':  
            opt->option_R = 1;
            break;
        default:
            exit(1);
            
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: just call `myprog -- -xyz`. `--` is recognized as 'end of options' by `getopt()`

Comment: i tried that, the problem is, if I want to say do ./myprog -i -xyz, to get the inode #, it it looks at -xyz individually cuz they are not options.

Comment: `i tried that` and it should have worked. So call `./myprog -i -- -xyz`. What have you tried?

Comment: Did you try `./myprog -i -- -xyz` ?  BTW: On invalid options I suggest to print an error message to `stderr` before exiting from the program.

Comment: I tried adding ./myprog -i -- -xyz, and it doesn't print the inode for -xyz.  For example, if i do ./myprog -i Makefile -- -xyz, it only prints:
806390 Makefile
but it doesn't print the inode number for -xyz

Comment: Please add an [mre] to the question. As the current code snippet is not sufficient to reproduce your problem

Comment: `it doesn't print` What is "it"? _What_ doesn't print? There is no code you have shown that would print anything. Maybe you meant for `-i` to take an argument, not be an option? I think I'll suggest to read the [manual for `getopt`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html). `./myprogram -i Makefile -xyz, I expect it to print both inode` Then do `./myprogram -i -- Makefile -xyz`. See [gnu argument syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html)and[posix utility conventions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)